# Tools for monitoring with my provider for db(mongodb)

Tags: windows, mongodb, memcached, monitoring

Is there any free tools for monitoring perfomance of cpu, memory, memcache(hits) for windows(i have asp.net mvc web site on windows server 2008 r2), which can use not only ms sql, but another db like **mongodb** for statistics, i.e. which provide to inject my own database provider.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at cacti, or munin. I use munin for monitoring mongodb.

Here is the mongodb monitoring page:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics

Munin memcached plugin:
http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/memcached-multigraph/details

Munin may not be the best option if you are all-windows, but here is there page on windows monitoring:
http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToMonitorWindows

You can find similar things for cacti but putting them together can be a little more work.

Comment: yes i am all-windows :) I dont' want to profile my mongodb, i want to store statistics about perfomance in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

10gen provide a free monitoring service: http://www.10gen.com/mongodb-monitoring-service

> MongoDB Monitoring Service (MMS) is a tool designed to help develop and manage MongoDB applications.
>
> MMS instruments MongoDB clusters, giving insight into current and historical operational metrics of your system. By logging and graphing these metrics, MMS gives you deep visibility into system performance, allowing you to optimize applications during development, or rapidly diagnose and fix problems that occur during production.

Installation on windows is easy - see the docs:
http://mms.10gen.com/help/install.html#installing-mms-on-windows